# Parent to Child Account Subscriber Filter

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have our Parent Account setup with multiple child accounts underneath it. The Subscriber Filter is setup so if a user has a certain storecode in a profile attribute it gets added to the matching child accounts 'all subscribers' list.

Each storecode and child account is a different website. The problem I'm facing is if a customer makes purchases on multiple websites their 'storecode' profile attribute gets updated with the most recent purchase and therefore overrides the current storecode.

Is there anyway around this so a subscriber can exist in multiple child accounts at once?

Comment: One profile attribute per storecode should solve your problem, if this is feasible in your setup

Answer (score 1):

As Profile Attributes are just one flat list, the way to achieve this would be to have one "Boolean" Attribute (it's really a text field, but you get the idea) per store instead of having the one storecode value inside one and the same field.

StoreCode1 - true / false

StoreCode2 - true / false

[...]

Of course a new store then requires a new attribute.
I am not suggesting that this is a highly skalable approach, but that's unfortunately how it works when dealing with Profile Attributes, which Subscriber Filters are based on.

General note on Subscriber Filters:

They only block the UI / "view" on All subscribers. It actually is still available for e.g. AMPScript and SQL as well as SSJS. So Subscriber Filters alone does not really technically isolate the data.

Run this SQL in your "filtered" child BU to test:

`SELECT SubscriberKey FROM ENT._Subscribers`

Run this in a cloudpage from your "filtered" child BU:

```
%%[
SET @record = Lookup("ENT._Subscribers","EmailAddress","SubscriberKey","ENTER ANY SUBSCRIBER KEY")
]%%

%%=v(@record)=%%
```

You will see data that should have been filtered in the result, regardless of the Subscriber Filter.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment so I post this as an answer)

This sounds like a solution architecture problem, however:

As long as the Subscriber object you mention links what you call a "User" (not clear what Salesforce object you are registering your users with, are they Customer Community Users?) with an Account —either parent or child— you should get the outcome you are looking for, i.e. having the user as subscriber to the different Accounts (websites) it had an interaction with.

From your story, it sounds like the store code is being used to create the subscriber record when a user interacts with a website and the meaningful data would be the Subscriber records (and linked Accounts) a User is registered under and not the latest store code it holds.

It would help with the assessment if you edit your question to explicitly mention the standard and custom objects involved in your use case and provide some screenshots of what you get vs what you need your data to be.